# spring + hibernate + data base connection pooling and high availability

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, cluster-computing, failover

I'm trying to configure my web application like this:
1 tomcat server 
2 mysql data bases in master/ master replication for failover purpose.

I also succeded to set up a pooled connexion using c3p0, thus avoiding to open a new connexion for each request(when no failover is involved)

I would like to use the failover support porvided by the jdbc connector in order to route request to the second database when the first one is unavailabe. Thus i'm using the fail over capability of the jdbc driver, simply by providing extra configuration parameters.

For the moment, when one server is unvailable, the requst are routed to the second available server. However, i'm facing a problem with a new opened connexion on the database for each request.

It seems that combaining connexion pooling and jdbc failover dosen't work toogther ?

Please advice, also regarding configuration parameters

```
<bean id="mydataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"     destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="jdbcUrl"  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306,myOtherServer:3306/zeus?autoCommit=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;autoReconnectForPools=true&amp;failOverReadOnly=false"/>
  <property name="user" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="root" /> 

  <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
  <!-- property name="acquireIncrement" value="${acquireIncrement}" /_-->
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="6" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
  <property name="maxIdleTime" value="100" />
</bean>
```